# Popular Select com registros do banco de dados Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde.

Estou tendo dificuldades em popular um select com registros do meu banco de dados.

Eu tenho uma tabela funcionários que se relaciona com outras 3 tabelas 
(Cargo, Setor e Departamento). Atualmente só consigo popular o select se o registro estiver na view, porém implementei a feature SoftDeletes do Laravel que
exclui um registro da view e  mantém o mesmo salvo no banco e quando eu faço isso, a informação já some do select.

Alguém pode me ajudar em puxar esses dados diretamente do banco?

A minha model de funcionários está assim:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Treinamento;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Funcionario extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome_funcionario', 'email_funcionario', 'instrutor', 
        'cargos_id', 'nome_cargo',
        'cetors_id', 'nome_cetor',
        'departamentos_id', 'nome_departamento',
    ];     

    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

}
```

A migration de funcionários está assim:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateFuncionarios extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('funcionarios', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nome_funcionario');
            $table->string('email_funcionario');
            $table->string('instrutor');
            $table->integer('cargos_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('cargos_id')->references('id')->on('cargos');
            $table->integer('cetors_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('cetors_id')->references('id')->on('cetors');
            $table->integer('departamentos_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('departamentos_id')->references('id')->on('departamentos');

            $table->softDeletes();

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('funcionarios');
    }
}
```

A view de funcionários está assim:

```
@extends('adminlte::page')

@section('title', 'Módulo de Treinamento')

@section('content_header')
    <center>
    <br>
    <h3 style="margin-top: -30px;">Gerenciador de Funcionários</h3>
    </center>
@stop

@section('content')
<br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 margin-tb">
            <div class="pull-right">
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target=" .bd-example-modal-lg">Incluir Funcionário</button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">

                <form action="{{ route('funcionarios.store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="container box box-success">
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Nome do Novo Funcionário:</strong>
                            <input type="text" name="nome_funcionario" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome..." required="ON">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Email do Novo Funcionário:</strong>
                            <input type="email" name="email_funcionario" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite o nome..." required="ON">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <strong>Ele é instrutor?</strong>
                            <select name="instrutor" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>
                            <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                            <option value="Nao">Não</option>
                            <select>   
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Selecione o Cargo</strong>
                            <select name="cargos_id" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>
                            @foreach ($classcargo_array as $cargos_id)
                                <option value="{{$cargos_id->id}}" > {{$cargos_id->nome_cargo}}</option>
                            @endforeach     
                            </select>    

                        </div>

                       <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Selecione o Setor</strong>
                            <select name="cetors_id" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>
                            @foreach ($classcetor_array as $cetors_id)
                                <option value="{{$cetors_id->id}}" > {{$cetors_id->nome_cetor}}</option>
                            @endforeach     
                            </select>   

                        </div> 

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <strong>Selecione o Departamento</strong>
                            <select name="departamentos_id" class="form-control" required="ON">
                            <option value="">Clique aqui</option>
                            @foreach ($classdepartamento_array as $departamentos_id)
                                 <option value="{{$departamentos_id->id}}" > {{$departamentos_id->nome_departamento}}</option>
                            @endforeach               
                            </select>   
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        </div> 

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                        <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button></center>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sic btn-success btn-block btn-flat ">Enviar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </form>
                </div>   
              </div>
            </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" class="init">

            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#tobarril').DataTable({
                    "language": {
                    "lengthMenu": "Visualizando _MENU_  itens por página",
                    "zeroRecords": "Item não encontrado",
                    "info": "Visualizando página _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
                    "infoEmpty": "No records available",
                    "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado from _MAX_ total records)"
                        }
                    } 
                );
            } );
        </script>

    </head>

    <br>
    <div class="container box box-success">
    </div>
    <br>
        <table id="tobarril" class="table table-bordered"> 

        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><center>N°</center></th>
            <th><center>Nome</center></th>
            <th><center>Email</center></th>
            <th><center>Instrutor</center></th>
            <th><center>Cargo</center></th>
            <th><center>Setor</center></th>
            <th><center>Departamento</center></th>
            <th width="150px"><center>Ação</center></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario)
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><center>{{ $funcionario->id }}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{ $funcionario->nome_funcionario }}</center></td>
            <th><center>{{ $funcionario->email_funcionario }}</center></th>
            <th><center>{{ $funcionario->instrutor }}</center></th>
            <th><center>{{ $funcionario->cargos_id }}</center></th> 
            <th><center>{{ $funcionario->cetors_id }}</center></th>
            <th><center>{{ $funcionario->departamentos_id }}</center></th>
            <td>
                <center>
                <form action="{{ route('funcionarios.destroy',$funcionario->id) }}" method="POST">



                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('funcionarios.edit',$funcionario->id) }}">Editar</a>


                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')


                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Deletar</button>
                </form>
            </center>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>


   {!! $funcionarios->links() !!}


@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Quando você quer retornar todos os resultados até mesmo os que já estão deletados, você usa:

```
\App\Funcionario::withTrashed()->get();
```

Isso pode ser colocado em relações também, assim:

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Model')->withTrashed();
```

E um detalhe, eu percebi que não há relações definidas na sua model do Funcionario, considere colocar relações `belongsTo`, como no comando acima.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
public function departamentos()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Departamentos::class, 'departamentos_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

Depois de definir as relações, você carrega elas assim:

```
\App\Funcionario::withTrashed()->with(['departamentos', ... e outras relações que você queira ...])->get();
```

Dessa forma, você obter todos os funcionários e também todas as informações sobre o departamento, cargo, etc.

Pelo que entendi do código, acredito que apenas usar `withTrashed` já lhe serve, mas fica aqui um a mais caso queira exibir o nome do departamento em vez do ID, por exemplo.

Caso queira ver documentação do SoftDeleting, ele menciona a função `withTrashed`, segue este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#soft-deleting).

E há também documentação sobre Eager Loading, que fala sobre a função `with`, segue este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#eager-loading).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, vou aplicar no código.